# JMeter construct payload from csv file

Tags: jmeter

I needed to construct an HTTP request body from a CSV file.
There are 3 columns (userID, SessionId, groupId) and 1000 userIDs in the CSV file.
The API I was testing had a requirement for bulk loading, and each bulk contains 200 userIDs.
Below is the sample of the payload:

```
{

  "data": [
    {
      "username": "<userID>",
      "remoteMeetingGroupName": "<groupID>"
    },
    {
      "username": "<userID>",
      "remoteMeetingGroupName": "<groupID>"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So based on the requirement of 200 users per bulk, I will need to create 5 concurrent users, each of while containing 200 users in the CSV file. Is ForEach controller able to do this? Could anyone gimme some hints? Thanks.

Comment: You can use (Groovy)[https://groovy-lang.org/json.html] to create the JSON payload dynamically inside a (JSR223 Pre Processor)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor]. Also you can use Groovy to read the data from CSV file. I will provide a workable solution later if you need.

Answer (score 0):

The request body can be constructed from the CSV file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), something like:

```
def start = (vars.get('__jm__Thread Group__idx') as int)

def offset = (start + 1) * 200

def payload = [:]
def data = []

start.upto(offset, { index ->
    def lineFromCsv = new File('test.csv').readLines().get(index)
    data.add(['username': lineFromCsv.split(',')[0]])
    data.add(['remoteMeetingGroupName': lineFromCsv.split(',')[1]])

})

payload.put('data', data)

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

Refer generated request body as `${payload}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)